# Stream implementation - override Dispose or DisposeAsync or both?

Tags: c#, stream, dispose

Most of the methods of the `System.IO.Stream` class are available as both a synchronous and an asynchronous variant.

For the read/write methods the documentation explicitly states that only the synchronous methods need to be overridden, and that the asynchronous methods will work out of the box.

But what about the dispose methods? Should I override `Dispose()` or `DisposeAsync()` or both in my own stream implementation?

If the guideline is the same as for the other methods (override only synchronous `Dispose()`), then there is a follow-up question: What if I need to do some asynchronous stuff on disposal - would I then implement both the synchronous and the asynchronous dispose?